# How to select several files by their names in shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell

For example, there are many files in the same path named like:

```
FILE-2013-01-02.csv, FILE-2013-01-03.csv,......FILE-2013-12-31.csv
```

I want to select several files and copy them into other path.

Simply, to select files containing the information for *January*, I use `cp -r FILE-2013-01* ./other/path`.

If I want to select all the files in Month 1, 3, 5, 7 with one sentence in shell, what should I do?

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

`cp -r FILE-2013-0{1,3,5,7}* ./other/path`

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
cp -r FILE-2013-0[1357]-*.csv your_path
```

Answer (score 1):

Use it as follows:

```
cp -r FILE-2013-0{1,3,5}* your_path
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cp -r FILE-2013-0[1357]-[0-3][0-9].csv /otherpath/
```

If you want to mach 2013-11 and 2013-02 but no 2013-12 or 2013-01 you could use grep -E -w to get more complex regexp options: `2013-(1[01]|0[2357])`

```
ls | grep -E -w '^FILE-2013-(1[01]|0[2357])-[0-3][0-9].csv$' | xargs -i cp {} /otherpath/
```

I prefer find to achieve this.

```
find ./ -type f -name "FILE-2013-0[1357]-[0-3][0-9].csv" -exec cp -r {} /otherpath/ \;
```